# Java: Removing duplicate words & substrings of words in java

Tags: java, string

Recently i have come up against a question which i am not able to tackle in school.

I need to remove duplicate words in an input string which consists of words. The main issue here is that the requirement states that i cannot use arrays or regular expressions.

E.g.

userInput = "this is a test testing is fun really fun"

- the first "is" is a duplicate of "this" as it is a substring
- the second "is" is a duplicate of the first "is"
- "testing" is not a duplicate of "test" as it is not an exact match

therefore the output comes out as -  "this a test testing fun really"

How would one actually achieve this without using Arrays or Regular Expressions as it is impossible to split the words up by the white spaces and dynamically create a String in java.

Comment: I'd use some kind of loop that called `indexOf`, `substring` and `contains` on the original `String`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think we're only looking backwards.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. The code or the algorithm, then from that point onwards the solution will come to shape.

Comment: Can you use collections?  `HashSet` for example?

Comment: @markspace nope we are not allowed to use any extra frameworks. The answer algoJava has provided below works fine though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't compile this code, but I think it should works.
Let me know if it can help you to solved your problem.

```
public String solve(String input) {
    String ret = "";
    int pos = 0;

    while(pos<input.length()) {
        // find next position of space
        int next = input.indexOf(' ',pos);

        // space not exists, skip next to end of string
        if(next==-1) next = input.length();

        // take 1 word from input
        String word = input.substring(pos,next);

        // check if word exists in previous result
        if(ret.indexOf(word)==-1) {
            if(ret.length() > 0) ret += " ";
            // append word to ret
            ret += word;
        }
        pos = next + 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I see, so the logic behind this is to create one variable and keep appending the words to it. Thank you so much good sir.